# In SQL SERVER, how to see multiple column values in new line

Tags: sql-server

I have a data present in SQL Server with following format

```
SA                  Path_Information

------                ------

One                 H drive - H:\baa\C,H Drive - H:\CAA\D, DES- F:\detail

-------             -------------

Two                  Oracle: H:\baa\C, Excel: H:\CAA\D
```

But, I want it in

```
SA      Path_Information
----------------
One       H Drive - H:\baa\C
           H Drive - H:\CAA\D
           DES - F:\detail

-------    -----------

Two        Oracle: H:\baa\C
           Excel: H:\CAA\D
```

With every path information in on a new line of the same row. So, can anyone please tell how to do that? Thanks

Comment: The absolute best option would be to stop storing delimited data in a single tuple like this. It violates 1NF and causes lots of pain.

Answer (score 0):

You store line breaks and carriage returns in the data, though you won't see this reflected in SSMS.

I use both together for good results across many applications, you'd want to stick `CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)` where you would want a line break.
In your case, if your commas are currently the divider, you can replace the commas with the aforementioned 2-character string.

You can store it as such, or query it that way for display purposes.

> Documentation with using CHAR: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/char-transact-sql

**Edit**:

If you want to select these values, you can use the REPLACE function as shown below:

```
SELECT
    SA
    ,REPLACE(path_information,',',char(13)+char(10))
FROM myTable
```

If you would want to update the database to actually store it that way, you would do the following:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET path_information = REPLACE(path_information,',',char(13)+char(10))
```

Comment: Can you please give me some query example? i am new to SQL SERVER and I did not understood the way to replace the commas with the aforementioned 2-character string